# Question about subqueries with specific conditions and same condition as query at the same time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using T-SQL for a few months and there is one thing I simply don't know how to do. Let's say we have a table created below

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
               (
                   id int,
                   status_FK int,
                   [value] int
               )
 
INSERT INTO @table (id, status_FK, [value])
VALUES (1, 1, 1000),
       (2, 1, 2000),
       (3, 2, 3000),
       (4, 1, 2000),
       (5, 2, 2000),
       (6, 2, 3000),
       (7, 5, 12000)

SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(value) WHERE status_FK = 1) AS 'status1',
    (SELECT SUM(value) WHERE status_FK = 2) AS 'status2'
FROM 
    @table
WHERE 
    value > 1500
```

What I'm trying to do is use condition value > 1500 for all subqueries but also each subquery have specific condition. Can someone please explain me how to do this simple thing without repeating whole main query in both subqueries with different conditions? Many thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like that:

```
SELECT
  SUM(case when status_FK = 1 then value else 0 end) as `status1`,
  SUM(case when status_FK = 2 then value else 0 end) as `status2`
FROM @table
WHERE value > 1500
```

Update 1:
You can have many as you like, best if you have small of column to display:

```
SELECT
  SUM(case when status_FK = 1 then value else 0 end) as `status1`,
  SUM(case when status_FK = 2 then value else 0 end) as `status2`,
  ...
  SUM(case when status_FK = n then value else 0 end) as `statusn`, 
FROM @table
WHERE value > 1500
```

For complex cases you can look at [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Thank you, that is a great solution, but is there something else for more complex queries with like 10 conditions on query and 10 more on subquery?

Comment: this is simply known as *conditional aggregation*. Also, column aliases should not be 'quoted'.

Comment: @Falcoonek Why can't you just put your 10 conditions in using the same pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT, a powerful operator.

```
CREATE  TABLE #TEMP
               (
                   id int,
                   status_FK int,
                   [value] int
               )
 
INSERT INTO #TEMP (id, status_FK, [value])
VALUES (1, 1, 1000),
       (2, 1, 2000),
       (3, 2, 3000),
       (4, 1, 2000),
       (5, 2, 2000),
       (6, 2, 3000),
       (7, 5, 12000)



    SELECT [1] AS status1, [2] AS status2
    FROM (SELECT status_FK, value FROM #TEMP WHERE value > 1500) AS T
    PIVOT(SUM([value]) FOR status_FK IN ([1], [2])) AS PT
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Join also

```
SELECT Status_fk
    ,sum(value)
FROM @table t
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES (1)
        ,(2)
    ) X(StatusID) ON t.status_FK = X.StatusID
WHERE value > 1500
GROUP BY status_FK
```